# Stop element being re-rendered when entering a new input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm writing simple challanges in React. I've created an input field which then renders the input value in a new paragraph. But when I type in a new text in the input field the first rendered element changes also. How can I stop the first element from changing every time I type something in the input field?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './css&sass/main.css';

function Main() {

    const [ item, setItem ] = useState("");
    const [ showItem, setShowItem ] = useState(false);

    const inputTargetValue = (e) => {
        setItem(e.target.value)
      }

      function onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(item)
    }

    const showData = (
        <p>
            {item}
        </p>
    )

    return (
        <form className='main--container' onSubmit={onSubmit}>

                <input type="text" className='data--input' placeholder='Text input' value={item} onChange={inputTargetValue}></input>
                <button className='data--button' onClick={() => setShowItem(true)}>Add item</button>
                {showItem ? showData : true}
        </form>
    )    

};

export default Main;
```

Comment: `the first rendered element` I'm not sure what element you're referring to. Can you clarify?

Comment: The input element 'data--input' renders the value as a paragraph in the 'showData' variable, when submited by button, it renders as the paragraph, but it is only one value, which is always replaced by the new input value, whitout clicking the submit 'data--button' button.
The 'showData' variable has a state of false and it is activated when submited by the change of state to true (const [ showItem, setShowItem ] = useState(false);) with {showItem ? showData : true}.
So basically it always renders only one paragraph which is re-rendered by a new input, without submiting it with the button.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below-mentioned **assumptions**:

1. User is able to add one or more `item`s
2. These `item`s are rendered just above the user-input
3. There is an `Add Item` button that will add one item to the display
4. There is a `form` which when submitted will `console.log` the items-list
5. For future extension, the form's submit may be used to send the data elsewhere (may be to backend, etc)

this following code-snippet may be a possible solution:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

// React function to render items and
// accept user-input for new items
const AddItems = () => {

// declare variables that need useState hook

// first, the item that will be rendered to hold the input
  const [item, setItem] = useState('');

// a list of items that will be rendered at the top
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState([]);

// method to handle change to input
  const handleInputChange = e => setItem(e.target.value);

// handle add button click (update items-list,
// reset item to empty, and prevent default)
  const handleAddBtnClick = (e) => setItemsList(
    prev => ([...prev, item]),
    setItem(''), e.preventDefault()
  );

// handle form-submit button click event
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  // send the list of items for further processing
    console.log(
      'form-submit clicked... sending items-list: ',
      itemsList.join()
    );
  };
  
  return (
    <div class='outerContainer'>
      {itemsList && itemsList.length > 0 && (
        <div class='itemsListContainer'>
          {itemsList.map(
            (itm, idx) => (
              <div key={idx} class='itemContainer'>
                <p>{itm}</p>
              </div>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div class='userInputOuter'>
          <input
            value={item}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <button onClick={handleAddBtnClick} >
            Add Item
          </button>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h4>DEMO</h4>
    <AddItems />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.outerContainer { background-color: #BBBBEE }
.itemsListContainer { border: 2px solid #EE6666 }
.userInputOuter {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id='react'/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation** is provided in-line in the above code-snippets as comments.

**Observations** perusing the code in OP's question

- The `showItem` (initially set to `false`) is set to `true` on button-click & remains the same
- This means, once the user clicks the button, the `item` rendered using `showData` viz exactly the same as the one within the `input` will be `shown` / displayed.
- Thus, when user changes the input, the `showData`'s `item` getting updated in real-time will be displayed

What is required is a way to hold more than one item. In the code-snippet this is achieved by using `itemsList`.

Comment: That solution answered more questions than I initially had :) Thank you very much for the code snippet and the explanation, I really appreciate it